# Why does PHP hang on pg_connect(PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

Fail to connect to the PostgreSQL Database
I'm on Windows 10 using html, javascript, postgreSQL & php8.3.2
Within javascript I'm executing an ajax request for a php program.
I have the same results in my trace output whether I'm capturing the php program
using eclipse or just letting it run.

When executed through Ajax the following occurs:
/*
When php comes to the following function it literally hangs
on pg_connect(postgreSQL access point)
+++

```
function openConnections ()
   {
     global $dbHandle,$file;

     $str = "host=" . _host . " port=" . _port . " dbname=" . _dbName . 
            " user=" . _user . " password=" . _pswd . " connect_timeout=" . 5;
     fwrite($file,">>Opening Database\n\n");
     fwrite($file,$str . "\n");
     fclose($file); 
     $dbHandle = pg_connect($str);
     $file = fopen("DBresults.txt", 'a');
     if (!$dbHandle)
     {
       fwrite($file, "<<< Connection failed >>>\n\n");
       shutdown('Connection attempt failed.');
     }
     else 
     {
       fwrite($file, "DATABASE NAME:" . pg_dbname($dbHandle) . "\n");
       fwrite($file, "HOSTNAME: " . pg_host($dbHandle) . "\n");
       fwrite($file, "PORT: " . pg_port($dbHandle) . "\n");
       fwrite($file,"\n\n");
     }
   }
```

+++

Eclipse reports: PHP Application(Waiting...)
DBresults.txt shows

---

```
  Starting trace with input -->{"0":0,"rtype":"calVars"}
  Requesting data from -->calVars
  >>Opening Database

  host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=info user=tom password=test connect_timeout=5
```

---

No errors are reported in the PHP log file

If I just execute the php program alone, it runs perfectly.
I also get the same results using eclipse.
With either of the above I get the following output:

TRACE with accessDB:

```
      Starting trace with input -->{"0":0,"rtype":"calVars"}
      Requesting data from -->calVars
      >>Opening Database

      host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=info user=tom password=test connect_timeout=5
      DATABASE NAME:info
      HOSTNAME: 127.0.0.1
      PORT: 5432

      Array >>>Closed DB <<<
      Returning json_encoded string:
      {"clk_12hr":"f","start_of_day":"480","end_of_day":"1020","lunch":"720",
      "lunch_len":"60","num_schedule_times":"5","sch_times":"{15,20,30,45,60}"}
#
```

I've included port 5432(PostgreSQL) and 9003(Xdebug) into the firewall input
I've even disabled the firewall.
I've searched for any possible solution found on the internet.
Implemented anything that could apply.
Same results.

The resource monitor lists the following dlls:
php_pdo_pgsql
php_pgsql
libcrypto-1_1-x64
libpq
libssl-1_1-x64
php8apache2_4
php8ts
php_xdebug-3.3.1-8.3-vs16-x86_64

Is there something I'm failing to set in some environment?